# Random Google Maps Marker from Array

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to add a custom marker from an array on Google Maps I have seen another question close to this but the code provided doesn't allow Google Maps API to pick the Marker Icon

```
 function button1(location) {
var get1 = prompt ("Enter First Coord");
var get2 = prompt ("Enter Second Coord");

var icons = [
"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Concept211/Google-Maps-Markers/master/images/marker_green.png",
"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Concept211/Google-Maps-Markers/master/images/marker_purple.png",
"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Concept211/Google-Maps-Markers/master/images/marker_orange.png",
"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Concept211/Google-Maps-Markers/master/images/marker_white.png",
"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Concept211/Google-Maps-Markers/master/images/marker_black.png",
"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Concept211/Google-Maps-Markers/master/images/marker_blue.png"

];
var items;
var center = new google.maps.LatLng(get1,get2);
map.panTo(center);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: center,
map: map,

icon: items[Math.floor(Math.random()*icons .length)]
});
```

I keep getting a "items is not defined".
If I define it above the code I get a different error saying 
"Cannot read property '3' of undefined" on the icon: items[Math.floor(Math.random()*icons .length)] code

If anyone knows the solution I would very much appreciate it, thanks!

Comment: Define `items` above the code and let us see.

Comment: Hiya, I did as you asked and now I get a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '5' of undefined" The random function seems to work, as the property number does keep changing, but no marker is set on the map.

Comment: Why are you declaring empty variable `items`?

Comment: I declared it because before it was saying not found, now the issue is that there's an error saying it cannot read the property

Comment: You are trying to get content of empty variable `items`... Replace `icon: items[...............]` with `icon: icons[.......]`

Comment: Yeah, thats it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get content of empty variable `items`... Replace

```
icon: items[Math.floor(Math.random()*icons .length)]
```

with:

```
icon: icons[Math.floor(Math.random()*icons .length)]
```

Because you haven't got saved pictures in variable `items` but in variable `icons`.